# Como llenar un select con un JSON con jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Buen dia, tengo este json

```
[
    {
      "index": 0, 
      "_id": "593028d3c69b792206793971", 
      "name": "Sanchez Stout", 
      "gender": "male", 
      "age": 33, 
      "email": "sanchezstout@inquala.com", 
      "eyeColor": "blue", 
      "phone": "+1 (833) 555-2739", 
      "favoriteFruit": "apple", 
      "balance": "$3,039.54", 
      "friends": [
        {
          "id": 0, 
          "name": "Mcmillan Flynn"
        }, 
        {
          "id": 1, 
          "name": "Roberson Medina"
        }, 
        {
          "id": 2, 
          "name": "Snider Williams"
        }
      ], 
      "company": "INQUALA", 
      "isActive": true
    }, 
    {
      "index": 1, 
      "_id": "593028d39409999eb39753cf", 
      "name": "Tate Walton", 
      "gender": "male", 
      "age": 28, 
      "email": "tatewalton@daisu.com", 
      "eyeColor": "green", 
      "phone": "+1 (924) 413-3044", 
      "favoriteFruit": "banana", 
      "balance": "$3,841.40", 
      "friends": [
        {
          "id": 0, 
          "name": "Johns Merritt"
        }, 
        {
          "id": 1, 
          "name": "Gwendolyn Vang"
        }, 
        {
          "id": 2, 
          "name": "Berger Gilmore"
        }
      ], 
      "company": "DAISU", 
      "isActive": true
    }
  ]
```

Quiero llenar el select con los names que están en la propiedad de friends, en donde friends es otro arreglo de objetos, pero al llenarlo sale undefined y si pongo por ejemplo 0, muestra el primer amigo

Adjunto mi codigo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio 6</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Informacion</h1>
    <table id="tablaPersonas"></table>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
table{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border: rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px solid;
}
th{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border: rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px solid;
}
td{
    border-collapse: separate;
    border: rgb(0, 0, 0) 1px solid;
}
```

JS-jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let encabezado = `
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Nombre</td>
                <td>Genero</td>
                <td>Edad</td>
                <td>Correo</td>
                <td>Color de ojos</td>
                <td>Telefono</td>
                <td>Fruta favorita</td>
                <td>Saldo</td>
                <td>Amigos</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    `;
    $('#tablaPersonas').append(encabezado);
    $.getJSON('js/ejercicio6.json', function(datos){
        console.log(datos)
        $.each(datos, function (dato) { 
            console.log(datos[dato].friends)
            const {friends} = datos[dato];
            $('#tablaPersonas').append(`
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>${datos[dato].name}</td>
                        <td>${datos[dato].gender}</td>
                        <td>${datos[dato].age}</td>
                        <td>${datos[dato].email}</td>
                        <td>${datos[dato].eyeColor}</td>
                        <td>${datos[dato].phone}</td>
                        <td>${datos[dato].favoriteFruit}</td>
                        <td>${datos[dato].balance}</td>
                        <td>
                            <select>
                                <option>${friends[dato].name}</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            `);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: itera el arreglo de friends para los items del combo, ya que solo pone el primero por el indice que ya traes, si fuesen mas registros lo siguiente en mostrar seria el item 1 y asi secuencialmente

Comment: podrias mostrar el codigo? no entendi bien

Answer (score 0):

Como lo dijo user33999, solo te hace falta iterar el array de friends. Por lo tanto tu js quedaría:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  let encabezado = `<thead><tr>
      <td>Nombre</td>
      <td>Genero</td>
      <td>Edad</td>
      <td>Correo</td>
      <td>Color de ojos</td>
      <td>Telefono</td>
      <td>Fruta favorita</td>
      <td>Saldo</td>
      <td>Amigos</td>
  </tr></thead>`;

  $('#tablaPersonas').append(encabezado);

  $.getJSON('js/ejercicio6.json', function (datos) {
   console.log(datos)
   $.each(datos, function (dato) {
    console.log(datos[dato].friends)
    const { friends } = datos[dato];
    // --- Se iteran los friends de cada persona ---
    var optionFriends = ``;
    for (let f = 0; f < friends.length; f++) {
      optionFriends += `<option>` + friends[f].name + `</option>`;
    }
    // --- termina iteración de friends de cada persona ---
    $('#tablaPersonas').append(`
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>${datos[dato].name}</td>
                    <td>${datos[dato].gender}</td>
                    <td>${datos[dato].age}</td>
                    <td>${datos[dato].email}</td>
                    <td>${datos[dato].eyeColor}</td>
                    <td>${datos[dato].phone}</td>
                    <td>${datos[dato].favoriteFruit}</td>
                    <td>${datos[dato].balance}</td>
                    <td>
                        <select>
                          `+ optionFriends + `
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
      `);
    });
  });
 });
```